# Matriz com strings no Visualg

Tags: string, algoritmo, matriz, visualg

Estou tendo dificuldade com a seguinte questão:

> Crie uma matriz M[21,10]. Faça a leitura de 10 nomes (com no máximo 20 caracteres) e armazene na primeira linha da matriz. Após a leitura, decomponha os nomes letra por letra e as armazene nas demais linhas da matriz a partir da segunda. Ao final, escreva a matriz.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
algoritmo "Exercício 4"
var
   m : vetor[1..21, 1..10] de caractere
   nome : caractere
   i, j : inteiro
inicio
   i := 1
   para j de 1 ate 10 faca
      repita
         escreva("Informe o nome: ")
         leia(m[i, j])
         se compr(m[i, j]) > 20 entao
            escreval("Informe um nome com no máx. 20 caracteres.")
         fimse
      ate compr(m[i, j]) <= 20
      fimrepita
   fimpara
   para i de 2 ate 21 faca
      para j de 1 ate compr(m[1, j]) faca
         escreval(copia(m[1, j], j, 1))
      fimpara
   fimpara
fimalgoritmo
```

Não estou conseguindo distribuir as letras na matriz, e o erro do meu código diz que está faltando um faça na 5ª linha de baixo para cima, mas o faça está ali.

Comment: Você já não fez essa pergunta? (Eu estava agora mesmo lendo ela)

Comment: Na verdade fiz hoje de manhã também, agora só corrigi de "Vetor" para "Matriz" no título.
Mas perguntei novamente hoje à tarde mostrando o algoritmo, não somente pedindo a explicação.

Comment: Ok, não é assim que deve ser feito. Todas as publicações podem ser editadas quando você bem entender. Como a publicação atual está melhor que a outra, mantenha esta como está. A outra será fechada.

Comment: Ah, foi mal. Jurava que tinha deletado a outra.

Comment: Relax, estou baixando o VisualG pra testar o código.

Comment: Beleza, valeu :)

Comment: Relacionadas:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206191/algoritmo-para-leitura-escrita-de-matrizes
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206782/strings-em-matriz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem vários erros no seu algoritmo. Eu refiz todo ele conforme o enunciado do exercício.

Tente usar nomes descritivos para suas variáveis. O segundo *loop* estava ao contrário e eu acho que a confusão foi justamente por causa dos nomes das variáveis. Mesmo que você esteja acostumado com a matemática e tenha fixo na mente que `i` e `j` são, respectivamente, referentes às linhas e colunas é melhor usar nomes mais descritivos.

No primeiro *loop* é possível deixar fixo (*hardcoded*) o índice da linha da matriz como **1**, afinal, os nomes só serão colocados na primeira linha, como diz o enunciado.

Ao invés de colocar o nome digitado na matriz, mesmo que inválido, eu criei uma variável chamada `nome` para validar antes se o nome estava dentro das regras, se sim, ele vai pra matriz, caso contrário, o `repita` continuará executando.

Até aí você estava indo bem, mas não consigo entender qual era o objetivo do bloco de código final.

O que eu fiz foi percorrer todas as colunas da matriz e, para cada coluna, percorrer todas as linhas disponíveis (2 - 21) fazendo com que a coluna receba 1 carácter da `string` que fica na primeira linha desta coluna.

---

```
algoritmo "Exercício 4"
var
   matriz: vetor[1..21, 1..10] de caractere
   nome: caractere
   linha, coluna, i : inteiro

inicio
   para coluna de 1 ate 10 faca
      repita
         escreva("Informe o nome: ")
         leia(nome)
         se compr(nome) > 20 entao
            escreval("Informe um nome com no máx. 20 caracteres.")
         fimse
      ate compr(nome) <= 20
      matriz[1, coluna] := nome
   fimpara

   para coluna de 1 ate 10 faca
      i := 1
      para linha de 2 ate 21 faca
         matriz[linha, coluna] := copia(matriz[1, coluna], i, 1)
         i := i + 1
      fimpara
   fimpara   

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções e dicas. Na hora da execução está dando o mesmo erro que no meu algoritmo. Diz que está faltando um faca, mas não está não. (faca da 5ª linha de baixo pra cima)

Comment: @Jow Eu editei a resposta, tinha um problema naquela linha mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Melhorei um pouco o código. Agora ele exibe o resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]